# Load html by click into div using query with href

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to change content in a `div` depending on a `href-clicking`. I'm a newbie at freeform scritpting so please be gentle on me.

So, I have this index.html with a `<div>` where I load three different local html pages (menu.html) -> restaurant menus. At the head of each menu.html I would like to have `<a href>`-links for changing menu in the  placed in the index.html.

My question is: 
How to I call for index.html once my href-link that I call with my script is situated inside of menu.html?

So far I have:

1. index.html loads the menu 'alacarte.html' in div id: 'result' by default.
2. I want to press link in 'alacarte.html' that makes say 'pizza.html' load in index.html div id: 'result'.
3. I really want the links to be placed graphically on top of the say 'pizza.html'-page.

In my index.html I have:

```
<article class="post-meny" id="meny">
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $("#alacarte").click(function(){
        $('#result').load('alacarte.html');
       });  
       $("#beverage").click(function(){
        $('#result').load('pizza.html');
       });  
       $("#beverage").click(function(){
        $('#result').load('beverage.html');
       });
   });
</script>
<div id="result"></div>

<script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
       $( '#result' ).load( 'alacarte.html' );
   });
</script>

</article>
```

And in the menu page 'alacarte.html'

```
<!-- Links in restaurant menu that loads in index.html div id: result -->
<ul class="menu-navbar">
  <li>
     <a id="#pizza" href="#">PIZZA</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a id="#alacarte" href="#">A LA CARTE</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <div id="#beverege" class="#">BEVERAGE</div>
  </li>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){

     $("#alacarte").click(function(){
         $('index.html#result').load('alacarte.html');
     });
     $("#beverage").click(function(){
         $('index.html#result').load('beverage.html');
     });
     $("#pizza").click(function(){
         $('index.html#result').load('pizza.html');
     }); 
  } 
 </script>
```

I hope you can follow my futile explanation. How should I do it?

Please help!

Comment: You dont need extra script for the menu in `alacarte.html` since the page it's gonna be loaded inside a `div` in `index.html`. Put the menu outside of that div so you are not gonna need to maintain it seperately in each page

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for your code?

Comment: Thanks. But with my design layout I want the links calling the script being at the top of each menu. So it's a design consideration I would like to find a clean solution for. When I put the links in index.html everything loads just fine, but again: I want the href:s to be on the page I load - at least graphically speaking.

Comment: I don't think jsfiddle works for my example since it refers between two different html files and also is fetching one html-file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading items dynamically into `index.html`, you should use the `.on()` method to bind and listen to events. You do not need to include any further jQuery in the individual pages themselves.

For your menu, I suggest including the hyperlinks as intended in the `href` attribute, and then use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default behavior.

```
<ul class="menu-navbar">
  <li>
     <a href="pizza.html">PIZZA</a>
  </li>
  <li>
     <a href="alacarte.html">A LA CARTE</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="beverage.html">BEVERAGE</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

In your **index.html**, you can take advantage of the `.on()` method:

```
$(function() {
    // Use .on() to bind click even on dynamically added elements
    $(document).on('click', '.menu-navbar a', function(e) {

        // Prevents default behavior
        // Clicking on <a> will not redirect the page
        e.preventDefault();

        // Get hyperlink, and load page
        $('#result').load($(this).attr('href'));
    });

    // Load the first link by default, when DOM is ready
    $('#result').load('alacarte.html');
});
```